# why are all my dialog screens showing at the same time? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

first of all sorry if my question is unclear, it's my first time here (I just started learning web development four months ago haha).

Chronology:
I'm making note-like web. Each note have edit and delete button, what i want is when i press edit button or delete button, one edit form or alert will be displayed and change will be applied to the specific note. The problem is, when i pressed edit button on one of my note, all dialog screen for all notes are being displayed and stacked like this: [All dialog screen are being displayed and stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1ChI.png)

Anyone know why and how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
const [text, setText] = useState('');
const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState('');
const [newText, setNewText] = useState('');
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [openAlert, setOpenAlert] = useState(false);
const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);
```

```
const newNote = () => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:8888/new', {
        title: title,
        text: text
    }).then((response) => {
        setNotes([...notes, response.data])
    })
};
const dataNotes = () => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:8888/')
        .then((response) => {
            setNotes(response.data)
        })
};
const deleteNote = (id) => {
    Axios.delete(`http://localhost:8888/${id}`)
        .then((response) => {
            setNotes(notes.filter(note => note._id !== id))
        })
};
const editNote = (id) => {
    Axios.patch(`http://localhost:8888/${id}`, {
        title: newTitle,
        text: newText
    }).then((response) => {
        const newNotes = notes.map(note => {
            if (note._id === `${id}`) {
                return { ...note, title: newTitle, text: newText }
            }
            return note
        });
        setNotes(newNotes)
    })
}
const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
};
const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
};
const handleClickOpenAlert = () => {
    setOpenAlert(true);
};
const handleCloseAlert = () => {
    setOpenAlert(false);
};
const handleClickOpenEdit = () => {
    setOpenEdit(true)
};
const handleCloseEdit = () => {
    setOpenEdit(false);
};
useEffect(() => {
    dataNotes();
}, []);
```

```
<section className='notes'>
    {notes.map((note) => (
        <div className="note-container" key={note._id}>
            <h3>
                {note.title}
            </h3>
            <p>
                {note.text}
            </p>
            <section className="tool-container">
                <img
                    src={PencilIcon}
                    alt='edit'
                    className="pencil"
                    onClick={handleClickOpenEdit}
                />
                <img
                    src={TrashIcon}
                    alt='delete'
                    className="trash"
                    onClick={handleClickOpenAlert}
                />
                <Dialog open={openAlert} onClose={handleCloseAlert} aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title" aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description">
                    <DialogTitle id='alert-dialog-title'>{'Are you sure want to delete this note?'}</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText id='alert-dialog-description'>
                            Once you delete this note, you can't get it back
                        </DialogContentText>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={handleCloseAlert}>Cancel</Button>
                        <Button onClick={(event) => {
                            deleteNote(note._id);
                            handleCloseAlert();
                        }}>Delete</Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
                <Dialog open={openEdit} onClose={handleCloseEdit}>
                    <DialogTitle>Edit note</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <TextField autoFocus type='text' id='new-title' label='New Note Title' fullWidth variant='standard' defaultValue={note.title} required onChange={(evt) => {
                            if (evt.target.value !== null) {
                                setNewTitle(evt.target.value)
                            } else {
                                setNewTitle(note.title)
                            }
                        }} />
                        <TextField type='text' id='new-text' label='New Note Text' fullWidth variant='standard' multiline defaultValue={note.text} required onChange={(evt) => {
                            if (evt.target.value !== null) {
                                setNewText(evt.target.value)
                            } else {
                                setNewText(note.text)
                            }
                        }} />
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={handleCloseEdit}>Cancel</Button>
                        <Button onClick={() => {
                            editNote(note._id);
                            handleCloseEdit();
                        }}>Edit Note</Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </section>
        </div>
    ))}
</section>
```

Edit: I tried Eureka answer, change some of my codes

```
const [openAlert, setOpenAlert] = useState({});
const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState({});
```

```
const handleClickOpenAlert = (id) => {
    console.log("handleClickOpenAlert has been called with id=", id, " and the starting value of openAlert is", JSON.stringify(openAlert))
    setOpenAlert({
        ...openAlert,
        [id]: true
    })
};
const handleCloseAlert = (id) => {
    console.log("handleCloseAlert has been called with id=", id, " and the starting value of openAlert is", JSON.stringify(openAlert))
    setOpenAlert({
        ...openAlert,
        [id]: false
    })
};
const handleClickOpenEdit = (id) => {
    console.log("handleClickOpenEdit has been called with id=", id, " and the starting value of openEdit is", JSON.stringify(openEdit))
    setOpenEdit({
        ...openEdit,
        [id]: true
    })
};
const handleCloseEdit = (id) => {
    console.log("handleCloseEdit has been called with id=", id, " and the starting value of openEdit is", JSON.stringify(openEdit))
    setOpenEdit({
        ...openEdit,
        [id]: false
    })
};
```

```
<section className="tool-container">
              <img
                src={PencilIcon}
                alt='edit'
                className="pencil"
                onClick={handleClickOpenEdit(note._id)}
              />
              <img
                src={TrashIcon}
                alt='delete'
                className="trash"
                onClick={handleClickOpenAlert(note._id)}
              />
              <Dialog open={openAlert[note._id]} onClose={handleCloseAlert(note._id)} aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title" aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description">
                <DialogTitle id='alert-dialog-title'>{'Are you sure want to delete this note?'}</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                  <DialogContentText id='alert-dialog-description'>
                    Once you delete this note, you can't get it back
                  </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                  <Button onClick={handleCloseAlert(note._id)}>Cancel</Button>
                  <Button onClick={(event) => {
                    deleteNote(note._id);
                    handleCloseAlert(note._id);
                  }}>Delete</Button>
                </DialogActions>
              </Dialog>
              <Dialog open={openEdit[note._id]} onClose={handleCloseEdit(note._id)}>
                <DialogTitle>Edit note</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                  <TextField autoFocus type='text' id='standard-required' label='New Note Title' fullWidth variant='standard' defaultValue={note.title} required onChange={(evt) => {
                    if (evt.target.value !== null) {
                      setNewTitle(evt.target.value)
                    } else {
                      setNewTitle(note.title)
                    }
                  }} />
                  <TextField type='text' id='standard-required' label='New Note Text' fullWidth variant='standard' multiline defaultValue={note.text} required onChange={(evt) => {
                    if (evt.target.value !== null) {
                      setNewText(evt.target.value)
                    } else {
                      setNewText(note.text)
                    }
                  }} />
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                  <Button onClick={handleCloseEdit(note._id)}>Cancel</Button>
                  <Button onClick={() => {
                    editNote(note._id);
                    handleCloseEdit(note._id);
                  }}>Edit Note</Button>
                </DialogActions>
              </Dialog>
            </section>
```

And now i got this error (it's like infinite loop i guess(?) my handler always called)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL8Be.png)
[Close handler are being called infinite times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTyzf.png)

Edit: it now worked, thanks to M Maaz Azhar idea (and i added some things), thank you very much! And thanks to Eureka for patiently answering my newbie question haha. Thanks all of you :D

Full code:

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PlusIcon from './plus.svg'
import Axios from 'axios'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';

import EditDialog from './EditDialog';
import DeleteDialog from './DeleteDialog';
import './NoteCard.css'

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const newNote = () => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:8888/new', {
      title: title,
      text: text
    }).then((response) => {
      setNotes([...notes, response.data])
    })
  };
  const dataNotes = () => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:8888/')
      .then((response) => {
        setNotes(response.data)
      })
  };
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dataNotes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <section className='header'>
        <h1>Notes</h1>
        <img
          src={PlusIcon}
          alt='new'
          className='new'
          onClick={handleClickOpen}
        />
      </section>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Create new note</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <TextField autoFocus type='text' id='standard-required' label='Note Title' fullWidth variant='standard' required onChange={(evt) => {
            setTitle(evt.target.value)
          }} />
          <TextField type='text' name='text' id='standard-required' label='Note Text' fullWidth variant='standard' multiline required onChange={(evt) => {
            setText(evt.target.value)
          }} />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={() => {
            newNote();
            handleClose();
          }}>Create Note</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      <section className='notes'>
        {notes.map((note) => (
          <div className="note-container" key={note._id}>
            <h3>
              {note.title}
            </h3>
            <p>
              {note.text}
            </p>
            <section className="tool-container">
              <EditDialog onNotesChange={setNotes} notes={notes} note={note} />
              <DeleteDialog onNotesChange={setNotes} notes={notes} note={note} title={'Are you sure want to delete this note?'} />
            </section>
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**DeleteDialog.jsx**

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import TrashIcon from './trash.svg'

export default function DeleteDialog({ onNotesChange, notes, note, title }) {
    const [openAlert, setOpenAlert] = useState(false);
    const deleteNote = (id) => {
        Axios.delete(`http://localhost:8888/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                onNotesChange(notes.filter(note => note._id !== id))
            })
    };
    const handleClickOpenAlert = () => {
        setOpenAlert(true);
    };
    const handleCloseAlert = () => {
        setOpenAlert(false);
    };


    return (
        <>
            <img
                src={TrashIcon}
                alt='delete'
                className="trash"
                onClick={handleClickOpenAlert}
            />
            <Dialog open={openAlert} onClose={handleCloseAlert} aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title" aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description">
                <DialogTitle id='alert-dialog-title'>{title}</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText id='alert-dialog-description'>
                        Once you delete this note, you can't get it back
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleCloseAlert}>Cancel</Button>
                    <Button onClick={(event) => {
                        deleteNote(note._id);
                        handleCloseAlert();
                    }}>Delete</Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </>
    )
}
```

**EditDialog.jsx**

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import PencilIcon from './pencil.svg'

export default function EditDialog({ onNotesChange, notes, note }) {
    const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState('');
    const [newText, setNewText] = useState('');
    const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);
    const handleCloseEdit = () => {
        setOpenEdit(false);
    };
    const handleClickOpenEdit = () => {
        setOpenEdit(true)
    };
    const editNote = (id) => {
        Axios.patch(`http://localhost:8888/${id}`, {
            title: newTitle,
            text: newText
        }).then(() => {
            const newNotes = notes.map(note => {
                if (note._id === `${id}`) {
                    return { ...note, title: newTitle, text: newText }
                }
                return note
            });
            onNotesChange(newNotes)
        })
    };
    return (
        <>
            <img
                src={PencilIcon}
                alt='edit'
                className="pencil"
                onClick={handleClickOpenEdit}
            />
            <Dialog open={openEdit} onClose={handleCloseEdit}>
                <DialogTitle>Edit Note</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <TextField autoFocus type='text' id='standard-required' label='New Note Title' fullWidth variant='standard' defaultValue={note.title} required onChange={(evt) => {
                        if (evt.target.value === null) {
                            setNewTitle(note.title)
                        } else {
                            setNewTitle(evt.target.value)
                        }
                    }} />
                    <TextField type='text' id='standard-required' label='New Note Text' fullWidth variant='standard' multiline defaultValue={note.text} required onChange={(evt) => {
                        if (evt.target.value === null) {
                            setNewText(note.text)
                        } else {
                            setNewText(evt.target.value)
                        }
                    }} />
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleCloseEdit}>Cancel</Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => {
                        editNote(note._id);
                        handleCloseEdit();
                    }}>Edit Note</Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and share complete code?

Comment: @SanketKarandikar code updated

Comment: Hi Muhammad - thank you! Two things. First, some of the console.log's are copy-pasted with the wrong function names. (But that is not the cause of your problem). Second, I wonder whether I gave you the wrong way to call the handlers. Can you try changing `{handleClickOpenEdit(note._id)}` to `{(event)=>{handleClickOpenEdit(note._id)}}`, etc?

Comment: Hello @Eureka, sorry and thanks for noticing. I was sleepy last night, i forgot to check function names haha. Now that i fixed it, it seems the close handler are being called infinite time, so i think close handler is at fault here.

Comment: Make sure _all_ the calls to the handlers (including the close handlers) are of this form: not `{handleClickOpenEdit(note._id)}` but `{(event)=>{handleClickOpenEdit(note._id)}}`. From what you describe, I suspect that one of them is still being called incorrectlhy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue: All dialogs are using a single state.**

**Solution:**

**Make a seperate component for DialogBox**

```
function DialogBox({note,title,content}) { 

   const [openAlert, setOpenAlert] = useState(false);
   const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);

   const handleClickOpenAlert = () => {
      setOpenAlert(true);
    }; 
   const handleCloseAlert = () => {
      setOpenAlert(false);
   };
   const handleClickOpenEdit = () => {
      setOpenEdit(true);
   };
   const handleCloseEdit = () => {
      setOpenEdit(false);
   }

    return (
        <Dialog open={openEdit} onClose={handleCloseEdit}>
            <DialogTitle>{title}</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                     {content}
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleCloseEdit}>Cancel</Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => {
                            editNote(note._id);
                            handleCloseEdit();
                           }}>Edit Note</Button>
                </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
    );
}
export default DialogBox;
```

**Use that component in main component**

```
<section className='notes'>
    {notes.map((note) => (
        <div className="note-container" key={note._id}>
            <h3>
                {note.title}
            </h3>
            <p>
                {note.text}
            </p>
            <section className="tool-container">
                <img
                    src={PencilIcon}
                    alt='edit'
                    className="pencil"
                    onClick={handleClickOpenEdit}
                />
                <img
                    src={TrashIcon}
                    alt='delete'
                    className="trash"
                    onClick={handleClickOpenAlert}
                />
                <DialogBox 
                   title={"Are you sure want to delete this note?"}
                   content={"Once you delete this note, you can't get it back"}
                   note={note}
                />
                <DialogBox 
                   title={"Edit Note"}
                   content={<EditComponent/>}
                   note={note}
                />
</section>
```

Comment: sorry, i edit my code a little bit. I already tried this but it make editNote and deleteNote function undefined, i can't copy editNote and deleteNote function to different component because those function needs [notes,setNotes] state

Answer (score 2):

## All your notes are sharing the same "open" state

This is why opening one note, opens them all.

```
const [openAlert, setOpenAlert] = useState(false);
const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);
```

I am not familiar with ReactJS but I am wondering whether something along these lines is possible. Instead of storing a single boolean in the state, store an object with an entry for each note. The keys in the object can be the note Ids. For simplicity you can also say that if a key is absent, the state is false. That way you can initialise with just an empty object.

```
const [openAlert, setOpenAlert] = useState({});
const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState({});
```

Then your handler functions can be of this form:

```
const handleClickOpenEdit = (id) => {

  console.log("handleClickOpenEdit has been called with id=",id," and the starting value of openEdit is",JSON.stringify(openEdit) )

  setOpenEdit({
    ...openEdit, 
    [id]: true
  })
};
```

This means, when you click Open for Edit, expect to be passed the Id of the note, and the process of opening is as follows:

1. Start with the old contents of the state variable.
2. Add an entry (or replace it if it already exists) for the note Id, saying `true`.
3. Return that as the new contents of the state variable.

You would call this handler with the note Id:

```
<img
  src={PencilIcon}
  alt='edit'
  className="pencil"
  onClick={
      (event)=>{
           handleClickOpenEdit(note._id)
      }
  }
/>
```

Thank you for correcting my syntax (I told you I am not an expert in React, haha!)

However I am worried that if you really have written `Dialog open={openEdit.[note._id]}` then that looks like a syntax error to me. I think you need `openEdit[note._id]`, i.e. without a `.` before the `[`.

In any case, can you edit your question to show this revised attempt, and also show the error messages you are getting? I've added a debugging `console.log` that might help trace the problem.

## Also I initially gave you a wrong way to call the handlers

I said this:

```
onClick={ handleClickOpenEdit(note._id) }
```

But I suspect what that does is *immediately* run the handler when you render the page.

By the way, this did not cause that to happen:

```
onClick={ handleClickOpenEdit }
```

because it did not have `()`. When you specify a function name without `()`, it is not run immediately. It is set to be run when needed.

Therefore we need to put inside the `{ }` some code that *defines* a function, that isn't immediately run. We want that function to only run when needed.

This should do it:

```
   onClick={ 
        (event) => {
             handleClickOpenEdit(note._id)
        }
    }
```

If that works, try simplifying to this:

```
    onClick={ (event) => handleClickOpenEdit(note._id) }
```

Comment: sorry i just edited my code a little bit. Hmmm i understand the idea but, i confused how to implement this. I tried `const handleClickOpenEdit = (id) =>{setOpenEdit({...openEdit, [id]: true})} ` and `<img src={PencilIcon} alt='edit' className="pencil" onClick={handleClickOpenEdit(note._id)} />`  and i got error (like a lot of error)

Comment: i forgot, i also add `<Dialog open={openEdit.[note._id]} onClose={handleCloseEdit}>`, still got error

Comment: Thank you for the update! I have updated my post now, include my error message and update on my code. Still got an error (looks like infinite loop error), i don't know why.